# Could not find module 'Data.CSV'

Tags: csv, haskell, module

So, i was coding for the first time in haskell and i was trying to read a csv file. But i got a problem with no installed module (Data.Csv) and I have no clue of what I have to do.

That was the code:

```
--import Lib(someFunc)
import Data.Csv

csvTest :: IO()
csvTest = do
  test_csv <- parseCSVFromFile "campeonato.csv"
  case test_csv of
    Right csv -> print(extractColumn csv 4 :: [Int])
    Left err -> print err
  
extractColumn :: Read t => Csv -> Int -> [t]
extractColumn csv n =
  [read(record !! n) | record <- csv
                   , length record > n
                   , record ?= [""]]
```

Comment: You need to install it with a package manager like `cabal`: `cabal install cassava`, or add it to the `.cabal` file if you are using Haskell stack.

Comment: can you help in in how to add it in the .cabal file?

Comment: you list it under the `build-dependends` section, probably there is already `base >= 4.9.1.0 && <5` listed there, so you add `cassava` (and perhaps with version constraints)

Comment: Is is something like that?
library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_teste
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5,
      cassava >= 0.5.2.0
  default-language: Haskell2010

Comment: yes, so you add thus by the `build-depends`.

Answer (score 0):

The [**`Data.Csv`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Csv.html) is not part of the `base` package, and thus it is not available without installing the package to which `Data.Csv` belongs: [**`cassava`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava/).

You thus need to install this package with a package manager. For example if you work with cabal, you can install this with:

```
cabal install cassava
```

If you work with [haskell-stack](/questions/tagged/haskell-stack), you can list it as a `build-depends` in the `library` or `executable` section for  example:

```
-- .cabal file
-- …
library:
  -- …
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
   ,  cassava
    -- …
-- …
```

Comment: my .cabal file keeps resetting every time I run the code

Comment: @ThiagoMelo: then you likely use the `stack.yaml`, and in that case you list this under the `extra-deps`.